# Secure way to host a minecraft server on dynamic ip

Tags: networking, server, minecraft

i would like to host a minecraft server on a server in our home network, and because our home network has dynamic ip i am wondering what the most secure way to host it is without using dyndns or vpns
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dynamic DNS provider such as NO-IP or DynDNS.

They would provide you with a host name that resolves to IP that you can set and change.